# Why are some typeofs faster than others in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

While playing around to see whether `if (val) {}` or `if (typeof val === '') {}` is faster (the difference is  pretty [negligible](http://jsperf.com/typeof-or-no-typeof), btw), I noticed that the `typeof` operator seems to have widely varying performance based on what you're comparing:

```
typeof obj === 'object'; // slowest by ~50%
typeof func === 'function';
typeof und === 'undefined'; // second-fastest
typeof bool === 'boolean';
typeof str === 'string';
typeof num === 'number'; // fastest
typeof nu === 'object';
```

Other than `object` and `number`, all the other values are pretty close, though there is variance. As I understand it, the `===` operator isn't doing any type coercion, so I figure that `typeof` must be the culprit. Why would it perform differently with different types?

[jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/typeof-function-and-object)

**Edit:**
After testing in more browsers, this seems to be a WebKit-based anomaly. Firefox (32) is not only consistent, but significantly out-performs other browsers.

Comment: Not sure how much it factors in...but functions are objects too.  JS has to know to return `"object"` only for objects that aren't functions.

Comment: This would better be asked in a forum frequented by engine developers or others whose idea of a fun weekend is digging into the engine sources. But it doesn't really matter now, does it.

Comment: That's an implementation detail and probably varies from browser to browser. The specification simply provides a table describing the output for a given input type.

Comment: @cHao Functions are objects with internal `[[Call]]` property. I don't think checking if there is that property could have a performance impact.

Comment: @Oriol: checking for a single property could add 50% to something that otherwise consumed two ops...

Comment: consider handling stuff like typeof new String(123), and it seems that objects are more complicated to handle.